# Is a static member initialized before the constructor is called?

Tags: c++, static, initialization, member

I have a class with a std::map static member. I initialize it in the same translation unit (same cpp file) before the implementation of the constructor body. My program fails without output. I found out the problem known as static initialization order fiasco but I don't think this could be the case.

```
class Test {
public:
    static std::map<std::string, Test*> a;
    Test(std::string ID) {
        /* in my complete code  (where constructor
         * implementation and map initialization
         * are in a separate Test.cpp file), this fails, maybe
         * because the map is not initialized at the time
         * the constructor is being called by a sub class of Test */
        a.insert({ID, this});
    }
};
```

The constructor is called by a `Subclass` of `Test` when I do some static initialization of other variables.
Is there any scenario where the constructor of `Test` is called before the map is initialized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Is there any scenario where the constructor of Test is called before
the map is initialized?"  Of course.  All that is required is that there
is a static instance of `Test` in some other translation unit than the
one in which the map is defined.  (Where the code for the constructor of
`Test` is defined is irrelevant.  What counts is where the static
instance of `Test` is defined.)

There are other possible scenarios as well: the constructor of some
other static object uses a local instance of `Test`, for example.

The usual solution for this problem is to use a factory method for the
map:

```
std::map<std::string, Test*>& Test::registry()
{
    static std::map<std::string, Test*> theOneAndOnly;
    return theOneAndOnly;
}
```

This will cause the map to be constructed the first time it is needed.

And which compiler are you using?  You can't specify an initializer for
a static member in the class definition unless the member is const and
has integral or enum type.

Comment: I use gcc 4.9.2 Windows porting (mingw-w64).
I initialize the map inside the cpp file of the class using the default constructor `mymap = {};` If i don't do so i get a linker error.

Another question: how can an object be constructed without the constructor code being executed, how can it be irrelevant?

Comment: That's what you're supposed to do.  In your question, you had the initialization in the class definition; that's not legal.

Comment: When the object is constructed, the constructor code will be executed.  But where (in what translation unit, etc.) the constructor code is situated is irrelevant; what counts is where the definition of the object being initialized is situated; unless it is in the same translation unit as the definition of the map, the order of initialization is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

`static` declaration within a C++ class defines an object that "belongs" to the class itself rather to an object created from that class.
This means the initialization of any `static` member should be declared in the Cpp file.

use the syntax:

```
std::map<std::string, Test*> Test::a = {};
```

So to your question, No there is no such scenario. All `static` members are always initialized before any class constructor is being called.

Comment: Except when they aren't.

Comment: No, they're not. If you define a static instance before the static member in the same translation unit, the instance will be initialised (calling the constructor) before the static member.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - I take your nuance, indeed if someone declares a static  `Test` object prior of the map initialization, then it will be called first

Comment: @NirMH And if they define it in a different translation unit, it's not specified which will be called first.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the standard says :-

The storage for objects with static storage duration (basic.stc.static) shall be zero-initialized (dcl.init) before any other initialization takes place. Zero-initialization and initialization with a constant expression are collectively called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization. Objects of POD types (basic.types) with static storage duration initialized with constant expressions (expr.const) shall be initialized before any dynamic initialization takes place. Objects with static storage duration defined in namespace scope in the same translation unit and dynamically initialized shall be initialized in the order in which their definition appears in the translation unit.

Comment: I think [basic.start.init]/4 is the more relevant paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to fix your problem is to make your map a `static` local to some function that returns a reference to it.  This function can be a translation unit private function or a `static` class method.

In general, dependencies between `static` global variables between translation unots is a bad idea, as the order of initialization is not fully defined in all cases.

A `static` local variable, under the standard, gets initialized before used exactly once.  Note that older versions of visual studio have issues with multiple thread initialization, but not newer versions.